# R use of loop for applying a function to ove variable in a dataframe

Tags: r

I was hoping for some guidance.

I have some data looking at temperature over 10 second periods.

Sample data frame as below (my data frame has over 3000 rows!):

```
x <- as.data.frame(seq(0,500, by=10))

set.seed(1234)

y <- as.data.frame(rnorm(51,38,2))

df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

X is time and Y is temperature.

Now i am rubbish with loops but i want to extract the median temperature from every 50 second break i.e. the median for every 5 elements in series. Hope that makes sense.

Have tried to play with loops all afternoon and now lost all hope...is this doable in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a crude way than using the package.
Split by 5, and apply median to the list.

```
x <- as.data.frame(seq(0,500, by=10))

set.seed(1234)

y <- as.data.frame(rnorm(51,38,2))

df <- data.frame(x,y)
colnames(df) = c("time", "temp")

a = split(df, rep(1:11 , each = 5))
res = sapply(a, function(x) {median(x$temp)})
```

Comment: can i ask another quick question - some of the elements in the temperature data are missing for example the first 5 elements are 36, NA, NA, 36, NA. The median using your code above comes back as NA rather than 36. Is it possible to do this using the above code?

Comment: median(value, na.rm=T)

Comment: hello, i am probably having difficulty explaining my self. i will try with some real data from the my cohort. y <- as.data.frame(c(NA,36,NA,NA,NA,37,38,38,38,39,NA,NA,37,37,36)) ...the medians from the code above would produce 38, 37 as it will ignore the NA as elements. I would like to see medians as 36, 38, 37. So taking the first 5 elements "NA, 36, NA, NA, NA"...there is only one temperature recorded i would like that value (36) returned. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant. median(c(36, NA, NA, NA, NA), na.rm = T)
 returns 36. So if you substitute median(x$temp) with median(x$temp, na.rm = T), it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `runMedian` from package TTR is what you are looking for

```
runMedian(df$y, 5)
```

There is also `rollmedian`, and more general `rollapply` in ZOO package.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to compute a rolling median?

The library `zoo` has a rolling median function

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(1234)
y <- as.data.frame(rnorm(51,38,2))
rollmedian(y,5)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is kind of what i want but instead of a rolling median a serial for every 5 elements for example median 1 of element 1:5, median 2 of element 6:10, median 3 of element 11:15 etc...hope that makes sense

Comment: In that case I would proceed with the answer provided by @won782.

Comment: Use `rollapply` with `by` argument: `rollapply(y, 5, median, by = 5)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck nice!